# Why is the autostart a directory and not a file in .config on Pi 3b+

Tags: file

Unable to open the autostart file to enable RealVNC to auto boot

Comment: `.config/autostart` **is** a directory.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're running Rasobian Stretch.

No idea what you are talking about re directory / file. Standard lxde autostart file is '~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart'

But RealVNC server is normally started from a systemd service file.
The easiest way to activate it is from the Configuration Utility (Start Menu / Preferences) or `sudo raspi-config` from the command line.

If you prefer to enable it manually you can use `sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced`